# Zbar Code128 decode wrong

Tags: barcode, zbar, zbar-sdk

I have a image below

[image]

I'm using zbar to read the barcode

```
zbarimg --version
```

**0.10**

```
zbarimg -d ./image.jpg
```

**CODE-128:10000400040021**

scanned 1 barcode symbols from 1 images in 0.11 seconds

Result is `10000400040021`, but the correct barcode is `10000439140021`

I'm using barcode reader online (https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/) and the result is `10000439140021`

[image]

is it a zbar bugs ?